# Compile a .php file which takes in 4 parameter from another php file?

Tags: php

I have a script which when compiled from the terminal passing the parameters something like this "php compile.php arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4" on the terminal starts displaying the output result which is something like 1)file created 2) file inclusion. etc.

Now I am trying to use system(php compile.php arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4) from another php file, but it will not execute the php file or will not show an output.

For example i even tried to create hello.php------
and tried using system(php hello.php); but it did not output anything on the browser.

Can anyone please help me out, I am new to php. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `/usr/lib/php` instead of just `php`? (If you're on a Linux system, at least)

Comment: You can include a php file from another php file and call it's functions.

Comment: I agree with Crontab, but here it's actually `/usr/bin/php`....

Comment: Thanks for the replies i did not try that out, and for including the file i cannot do that as it is not arranged properly in functions and my compile.php file is calling 10 other files in a for loop.

Comment: I am using a mac right now, i will show you my code$file = "path/compile.php"; 
$f2 = "/path/"; 
$f3  = "path/";
$f4="path/"; 
$f5 = "/path/";


$program = "php -f ". $file . ' ' . $f2 . ' '. $f3. ' '. $f4. ' '. $f5;

system($program);

Answer (score 0):

make sure you react on errors from the system call. Your actual code might also help. The following example works without problems on my box.

```
<?php

$file = fopen('/tmp/written.php', 'w');

fwrite($file, '<?php echo "Hello from written.php\n"; ?>');
fclose($file);

echo "calling written.php\n";
if (!system('php /tmp/written.php'))
    die("something wrong\n");
else
    exit("all good\n");

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i just tried to just compile a simple hello.php file and it gave something is wrong , used the similar code you gave me if (!system('/usr/bin/php hello.php'))
 die("Something is wrong");

Comment: as you're on a mac, open up a terminal and enter `which php`. If nothing shows up, you have to include (or install) a php interpreter in your include_path().

Comment: also i am able to write into the file but compile is not working, nothing is getting displayed on my browser.